# iperf trafic generator via 2 NIC's using Dispatch Proxy

Tags: proxy, dispatch, nic, iperf, iperf3

I am attempting to run a test between two machines running windows 7 connected to an access point (isolated from any other network).

I need to split traffic from a traffic generator like Iperf3 between 2 Network Interfaces (WIFI) connected to the same AP. I am attempting to split the traffic using Dispatch Proxy. I have set this up with a socks proxy on localhost:1080

All devices have fixed IP's:

```
AP: 192.168.1.10

Device One: - Client
    NIC 1: 192.168.1.3
    NIC 2: 192.168.1.4

Device Two: - Server: 192.168.1.5
```

So far I have managed to get iperf to generate data from Device 1 to Device 2, however traffic is not split between the two NIC's, it is only sent via one.
Any help or suggestions would be useful.

Thanks
Gui

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to start two iperf streams and bind them to the output NIC.   In iperf 2 it will be:

- iperf -c 192.168.1.5 -B 192.168.1.3
- iperf -c 192.168.1.5 -B 192.168.1.4

But [this may not be enough](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/issues/3991) because the [-B only binds the src IP](http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2009/10/code-snippet-sobindtodevice.html) address in the packet and does not necessarily set the src output device (or NIC.)   To get the computer running Linux to use the proper NIC something like [policy routing](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/29/a-quick-introduction-to-linux-policy-routing/) is required.  (Not sure about Windows 7)

- ip rule add from 192.168.1.3 table 101
- ip rule add from 192.168.1.4 table 102
- ip route replace 192.168.1.5/32 dev *nic1* table 101
- ip route replace 192.168.1.5/32 dev *nic2* table 102
- ip route flush cache
- ip rule list

Also, the arp needs to be considered, particularly [arp_filter and arp_ignore.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt)

Then some higher level code needs to support summing of the two iperf sessions. 
 There is some beginnings of higher level python code in the [iperf2 flows](https://sourceforge.net/p/iperf2/code/ci/master/tree/flows/) directory.  This code does require ssh to work and assumes [ssh passwordless](https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/) operation.

Note: ipv6 does support link local and device binding via something like:

- iperf -c fe80::d03a:d127:75d2:4112%eno1

If you can use v6 and link local addressing it would be an easier way to do this.

Bob